# Autohotkey Cannot get "A_Language" to work

Tags: autohotkey

I use two different languages. 
I would like to switch Capslock and LShift, but only for one of them.

Basically I want to do this:

```
if (A_Language = "0409")
{  
   Capslock::LShift  
   LShift::Capslock  
}
// else behave like normal
```

When I write it like this, the keys are always swapped, no matter the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `#if` to create context-sensitive hotkeys.

You can read more here: http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_If.htm

Also, make sure you're running the [latest version of AHK](http://ahkscript.org/download/), otherwise it might not work.

```
#if (A_Language = "0409")
   Capslock::LShift  
   LShift::Capslock  
#if
```

Comment: I think your code works but it did not solve my problem. It appears the language code does not change when using Alt+Shift. I guess that is because it does not change the default language.
Anyway I came up with another idea that works for me.
I am now using Capslock::Shift, and LShift still acts as shift. But when combined they act like Capslock.

Comment: Capslock::Shift
    state = ""
    +Capslock::
    GetKeyState, state, CapsLock, T
    if (state = "D")
        SetCapslockState Off
    else
        SetCapslockState On
    return